# Flutterfire configure error. Unhandled exceotion

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, macos

When trying to run Flutterfire Configure Command, i'm getting the following error:

Unhandled exception:

```
Exception: /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:86:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:86:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

#0      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:540:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:///Users/mustafa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterfire_cli-0.2.7/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

When trying to install xcodeproj using gemfile I'm unable to as I don't have user permission even with sudo, so I tried installing xcodeproj using brew and i'm getiing the following error:

Error: xcproj has been disabled because it no license for the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating ruby to the newest version. Since Macbooks come with preinstalled ruby, flutterfire ends up using that version of ruby thus showing this error. This can be fixed by installing the newest version of ruby and changing the path of that version of ruby so you are able to run flutterfire.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Mustafa is absolutely correct and I just want to add the following to help someone struggling with the issue.

For some reason I still faced issue with Ruby version 3.3.0 so I downgraded it to 2.6.10 using rbenv(and not using brew install).
Along with the above I also executed

```
gem install xcodeproj
```

Another issue was that I executed sudo gem install which installed only one package and did not resolve the issue at all. So please try using only gem install to resolve the error completely.